# How do I get back the standard UAE exception dialog in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, unhandled-exception

I have an Exception Filer that is installed with `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`.

This exception filter does only write a minidump file and returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`.

Now I wondered that on a Windows 10 machine, my dump is written, but no additional message shows up.
I started to test without any exception filter and again: I didn't get any dialog.

Upon a crash an application silently exits without any UAE message also without the well known old dialog to send the information to MS. I can see the entries about the crash in the eventlog.

Further info:

- Get/SetErrorMode is 0
- The machine I tested it, was a plain fresh Windows 10 (no development software/ debugger installed)
- The application is using MFC
- Compiler and Framework = VS-2019
- The application is 32bit

Comment: Are you sure this is strictly related to Windows 10 (as opposed to the target architecture)? Exception handling has changed significantly for x64.

Comment: Hm. I am not sure, but I remember that I saw the error boxes under Windows 7 and Windows 8..1, but currently I have only Win10, and mostly all of my customers use Win10. And it is a 32bit application forgot to mention.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1246626/is-it-by-design-that-windows-10-no-longer-displays-app-has-stopped-working-d